# Take data from a Varray of oracle with java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

So I need to to take data from a Varray I created on Oracle with java program. If someone knows. I tried this

My VArray.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE cancion IS VARRAY(13) of VARCHAR2(20);/
```

My function in java.

```
private ArrayList<String> getCanciones(int codDisco) {
    this.open();//open connection
    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    String util;
    String sql = "SELECT canciones from TDisco where codDisco = "+codDisco;
    try {
        PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.println(sql);
        ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            util=rs.getString(1);
            x.add(util);
        };

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    this.close();//close connection
    return x;
}
```

Comment: What does "It just come with null values" mean? Please show the result you expect and what the result it instead.

Comment: I got three values in the VArray: ''a","e","i". But in the array when I try to show the data I just get null in the console so theArrayList is empty.

Comment: Did you execute the SQL query directly to check if it returns the correct result? Where do you print the result? You just show us one method, but not how you call it or where you output the result.

Comment: Yes solved the problem was that I was using an ArrayList and adding one by one. And I needed an array and add all of them like this   array = (ARRAY) rs.getArray(1); Thx for the help anyway

Comment: Great! But instead of editing your question, you can post your solution as answer. Because as of right now, it looks like your problem was unsolved.

Comment: Done ty for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple array doesn´t give problems to take all the data. So I just do it this way and working fine.

```
private ArrayList<String> getCanciones(int codDisco) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> x=new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] values = null;
    ARRAY array;
    String sql = "SELECT canciones from TDisco where codDisco = "+codDisco;
    try {
        PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.println(sql);
        ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            array = (ARRAY) rs.getArray(1);
            values = (String[]) array.getArray();
        };

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         x.add(values[i]);  
    }

    return x;
}
```